# Error to create user with API Google Admin-sdk

Tags: php, api, createuser, google-admin-sdk

I have the following code which me serves to get information such as mailing list etc ... But when I try to create a new mails (user) I get the following error, hope you can help me I tried to find more information but only find old api . This is the error-> : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBoqa.png

```
C:\xampp\php>php -f "c:\Users\Eldelaguila77\Desktop\proyectocorreos\quickstart1.php"

Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users: (403) Insufficient Permission
```

---

And this is my code

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Directory API PHP Quickstart');
    define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-php-quickstart.json');
    define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret1.json');
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-php-quickstart.json
    define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
      //Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY)
      Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER)
    ));

    if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
      throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
    }

    /**
     * Returns an authorized API client.
     * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
     */
    function getClient() {
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
      $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
      $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
      $client->setAccessType('offline');

      // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
      $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
      if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
      } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
          mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 777, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
      }
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

      // Refresh the token if it's expired.
      if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
      }
      return $client;
    }

    /**
     * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
     * @param string $path the path to expand.
     * @return string the expanded path.
     */
    function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
      $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
      if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
      }
      return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
    }

    // Get the API client and construct the service object.
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

    //enviar creacion de usuario
    $user = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
    $name = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();
    // SET THE ATTRIBUTES
    $name->setGivenName('pruebanueve');
    $name->setFamilyName('Testerton');
    $user->setName($name);
    $user->setHashFunction("MD5");
    $user->setPrimaryEmail("prueba@dom.com");
    $user->setPassword(hash("md5","holamundo"));


    try 
    { 
        $createUserResult = $service -> users -> insert($user); 
        var_dump($createUserResult); 
    } 
    catch (Google_IO_Exception $gioe) 
    { 
        echo "Error in connection: ".$gioe->getMessage(); 
    } 
    catch (Google_Service_Exception $gse) 
    { 
        echo $gse->getMessage(); 
    } 

    //print $results;


    // Print the first 10 users in the domain.
    /*$optParams = array(
      'customer' => 'my_customer',
      'maxResults' => 10,
      'orderBy' => 'email',
    );
    $results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);

    if (count($results->getUsers()) == 0) {
      print "No users found.\n";
    } else {
      print "Users:\n";
      foreach ($results->getUsers() as $user) {
        printf("%s (%s) (%s) \n", $user->getPrimaryEmail(),
            $user->getName()->getFullName(),
            $user->getlastLoginTime());
      }
    }*/
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To [create a user account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user) using one of your domains, use the following POST request and include the authorization described in Authorize requests.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

Please note that every request your application sends to the Directory API must include an authorization token.

Comment: I tried $ client-> setScopes ( array ( ' https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users '));

but I get the same error 403, I'm sending the authorization signal , see my code of above

Answer (score 0):

Your question helped me a lot. I was doing exactly what you was doing, but trying to do the JSON by hand. Anyways, I solved your problem:

You have to delete the ~/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-php-quickstart.json (you created it with the ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY scope, which is now not sufficient any more. Once you deleted it, the script will generate a new one for you. And then it all works. (users end up being suspended though) Add a

```
$user->setSuspended(false);
```